# Reading Data From PLC With Defined Tags

Tags: c#, .net, plc

I need to read data from PLC(Siemens S7300) with predefined tags. I got addresses of these datas but i can not use their addresses because of customer request. I can't handle this issue. I tried some libraries like (S7.NET) but i cannot do.

This is sample table that I have
[image: This is sample table that I have]

I tried some of coding but none of them give me correct result.

If I try

> plc.Read("MD40")

for reading first line's value it give me the value.
But as I said I cannot use address of value like (`MD40,DB100.DBX0 etc`). I need to read the value like

> plc.Read("SP_Bası_1")

.

Or If I wanna read second line value I have to use something like `bool data = plc.Read("HMI_Start");` instead of `bool data = plc.Read("MD20.0");`

Does anybody have any suggestion ?

Comment: IEEE754 is floating point numbers and since it is four bytes it is a singe in c#.  The correct way of reading data is to put into a BinaryStream Class and read one type at a time.  Pretty simple for me since I'm an EE and done this hundreds of times before.  I suspect you have to program these devices and need to convert the output of the compiler to a memory block.  The data is probably in order so using BinaryStream first read a single (four bytes), then a one byte bool, and then another one byte bool.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer. My problem is not datatype. For ex. if i need to read second line, i have to use bool data = plc.Read("HMI_Start"); insted of plc.Read("MD20.0"). Is this clear? English is not my native language and I have problem with explain my problem

Comment: Then put two strings into the class both the PLC tag and the Address.  You can have two dictionaries if necessarry one that looks up by PLC tag and other that looks up by address name.

Comment: But it is almost same thing with accessing adresses of data. In this method I define first, address and then access via tag, I need access without defining any address in C# code. I'm new with PLC's, can't I access directly PLC tag, without defining in C# code any address ? (defining tags in PLC memory ?)

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the customers request.  Internally in your code you need the address.  The customer just want to look up values by name.  If for security reasons he doesn't want you to create the address in a table then you need to dynamically get the data by sequentially going through the table until you get the data (much slower).

Comment: Actually I offer them the mapping method but they refused. If you say there is no method without using address, I will talk them again. Thanks for your helping.

Comment: The PLC has a JTAG interface which is a serial data stream.  To get access to internal logic you load the JTAG with an address and then read or write data to the device.  Your table looks like the output of the VHDL compiler.  After being compiled the logic had to be assigned to logic blocks inside the PLC.  The PLC has a combination of fixed type blocks user defined blocks.

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut I am very interested in this question, if you had realized how to do it please share, thx.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to solve your problem, and for me the best, is to use an OPC UA Server ...

I believe that some recent S7 models may have a built-in OPC UA Server

It would also be theoretically possible using another PLC brand that supports Ethernet/IP protocol, for example Omron or AB, with Ethernet/IP it is possible to reference variables by name and not by memory address but I think this functionality is only present in high level PLC's.

Anyway what you intend to do is not possible with raw S7 protocol

Answer (score -1):

Build a memory map.  Read data into a byte array.  Then you can convert data using BitConverter using the address (offset into array).  So you need to create a dictionary using the class below.  You can then look up address in the dictionary.  To build the dictionary read one line of the table to add one entry into dictionary.

```
    class Map
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Map> dict = new Dictionary<string, Map>();

        string name { get; set; }
        long address { get; set; }
        Type _type { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: But it is almost same thing with accessing adresses of data. In this method I define first, address and then access via tag, I need access without defining any address in C# code

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut if OPC is no choice for you, I think this approach is not so wrong and maybe the closest you can get. Maybe you can write the memory map inside S7. Another advantage is you could resolve the addresses there. Then the only address you have to define in your C# code is the address of this map.

Comment: I think the op is building a tool to modify ram blocks inside the PLC.  Since different PLCs will have different number of ram blocks and different location the customer doesn't want the ram blocks locations hard coded.  Then each ram block will have variables that also have to be address by the name and not the address.